# content tab inside content tab jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LsB7Y/) that have `tab content` my problem is how should i insert another set of `tab content` inside.

**js**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('ul.tabs li').click(function(){
        var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

        $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('current');
        $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

        $(this).addClass('current');
        $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
    })

})
```

Image below show what I want to achieve hope this make sense

[image: tab content]

Answer (score 1):

Check [in this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kostisalex/nXPVh/) for a solution to your problem. The idea was to stop propagating the click event of the nested tabs group to the parent tab group. For this reason, I use the  **e.stopPropagation()** function on the click event. This prevents, the click event of the parent tabs group and the correct functionality of the child tabs group. Hope it helps!

```
('ul.tabs2 li').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    var tab_id = $(this).attr('data-tab');

    $('ul.tabs2 li').removeClass('current');
    $('.tab-content').removeClass('current');

    $(this).addClass('current');
    $("#"+tab_id).addClass('current');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.adipalaz.com/experiments/jquery/nested_accordion_demo.html

This is a good example of having an accordion within an accordion.

Hope this helps!